# Get LP from a .mod file, solve it with GLPK and get the output in a usable form

Tags: java, linear-programming, glpk

I have a .mod file and want to solve the LP within it with GLPK.

I know there is a method by using the cmd (Windows) with `glpsol -m name.mod` but then I will have to parse the output result which I want to avoid.

Is there a method by using the *glpk libraries for Java* to get the .mod file solve it and then get the output without the parsing and cmd part?

Comment: So I have found an Example: **mplsamp2**. The problem is that, although I tested exactly the same example in Java `ret = glp_mpl_read_model(tran, "sudoku.mod", 0);` gives 1, which makes me think, that the libraries are not installed properly. I have also tested the same code in another machine and although the "mip" example runs properly, when I copy paste the code from the "mplsamp2" the libraries are not even getting recognized.

Comment: My bad. I found my error. Under the name of the file, I had to write also the directory in which the file is located.

Comment: I am getting the output printed in the console. I still do not know how to get the value from the objective funtion and variables without manually parsing them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is possible way to get the output of glpk without parsing it manually.
The following code is from an answer seen from this link: [Input/output in GLPK for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158637/input-output-in-glpk-for-java)

```
static void writeMipSolution(glp_prob lp) {

 String name = GLPK.glp_get_obj_name(lp);
 double val = GLPK.glp_mip_obj_val(lp);

 System.out.println(name + " = " + val);

 int n = GLPK.glp_get_num_cols(lp);

 for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     name = GLPK.glp_get_col_name(lp, i);
     val = GLPK.glp_mip_col_val(lp, i);
     System.out.println(name + " = " + val);
 }
}
```